# deserialize and convert to another class using Linq and Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have a model like this

```
private class CPDocs
{
    public string DocumentDetails { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

and an instance of List of this class holds data like this

```
List<CPDocs> cd = new List<CPDocs>();
CPDocs cpd = new CPDocs();
cpd.DocumentDetails = "{\"name\":\"John\", \"age\":30, \"car\":null}";
cpd.IsApproved = false;
cd.Add(cpd);
```

(Real data is coming from external source and I don't have control over it. so can't change how data is added to the list)

I want to deserialize the json string and construct a class like this. So that `DocumentDetails` and `IsApproved`  comes inside a single class

```
public class person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string car { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this using newtonsoft json and Linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me show you two different ways (a naive implementation and a more advanced one)

#### Before we get started

In order to be able to test the solution I've applied some minor changes to your classes

```
public class CPDocs
{
    public string DocumentDetails { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Car { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

- `CPDocs` became `public`
- `person` became `Person`
- All properties of `Person` uses Pascal Casing

Let's have some sample data to play with

```
List<CPDocs> cd = new()
{
    new() { DocumentDetails = "{\"name\":\"John\", \"age\":30, \"car\":null}", IsApproved = false },
    new() { DocumentDetails = "{\"name\":\"Jane\", \"age\":27, \"car\":null}", IsApproved = true },
    new() { DocumentDetails = "{\"name\":\"Doe\", \"age\":null, \"car\":null}", IsApproved = false },
};
```

- Here I have used object (for `CPDocs`) and collection (for `List<CPDocs>` [initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) to make the object creation more concise
- I have also used C# 9's [Target-typed new expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new) (`new ()`) to make the object creation even more concise

#### Naive approach

```
var result = from doc in cd
let semiParsed = JObject.Parse(doc.DocumentDetails)
select new Person
{
    Name = (string)semiParsed[nameof(Person.Name).ToLower()],
    Age = (string)semiParsed[nameof(Person.Age).ToLower()],
    Car = (string)semiParsed[nameof(Person.Car).ToLower()],
    IsApproved = doc.IsApproved
};

foreach (var item in result)
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} ({item.Age}): '{item.Car}' {item.IsApproved}");
```

- I've introduced a temp variable during the iteration called `semiParsed` to store the semi parsed json
- With the `select` statement I've created a new `Person` for each and every `doc`
- The `semiParsed` index operator requires the field name

  - Because we have used Pascal Casing in the C# object and camel Casing in the json that's why we need to define a conversion between them `nameof(Person.Age).ToLower()`
  - The index operator returns a `JToken` which needs to be [converted](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit.htm) to `string`

#### (Bit) more advanced approach

The above code is hard to maintain because it's repetitive (`(string)semiParsed[nameof(Person....).ToLower()]`).

Also what if the mapping between the json fields and C# property names are not that straight forward?

Let's define a mapping separately from the `select` statement

```
Dictionary<string, string> mapping = new()
{
    { nameof(Person.Name), "name" },
    { nameof(Person.Age), "age" },
    { nameof(Person.Car), "car" },
};
```

Of course if you have control over the `Person` class then you might prefer the [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationattributes.htm) instead this custom mapping.

We can also define a function (or a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)) which receives the semi parsed json and a property selector (`p => p.Name`) and does all the magic

```
string GetValueBasedOnSelector(JObject source, Expression<Func<Person, string>> propSelector) 
{
    var expression = (MemberExpression)propSelector.Body;
    var propName = expression.Member.Name;
    var fieldName = mapping[propName];

    return (string)source[fieldName];
};
```

With this in our hand the Linq query looks like this:

```
result = from doc in cd
        let semiParsed = JObject.Parse(doc.DocumentDetails)
        select new Person
        {
            Name = GetValueBasedOnSelector(semiParsed, p => p.Name),
            Age = GetValueBasedOnSelector(semiParsed, p => p.Age),
            Car = GetValueBasedOnSelector(semiParsed, p => p.Car),
            IsApproved = doc.IsApproved

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<person>(cpd.DocumentDetails);
person.IsApproved=cpd.IsApproved;
```

person in json format

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": "30",
  "car": null,
  "IsApproved": false
}
```